# A problem about closed 2-forms on Minkowski space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity, hyperbolic-pde

The problem is:

For any closed 2-form in the Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$ satisfiying $dF=0$ and $\delta F \ne 0$ (with $\delta$ denoting the codifferential), does there exist a Lorentz manifold $(M,g)$ and a corrsponding diffeomorpism $f:M\to\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$ such that the pullback of $F$ on $M$, $f^{*}F$, satisfies $d(f^{*}F)=0$ and $\delta(f^{*}F)=0$?

Comment: Well, the condition on $d(f^*F)$ is automatic since exterior derivative commutes with pullbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question can be equivalently phrased as:

> Given a closed two-form $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$, is it always possible to find a Lorentzian metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\delta F = 0$.

Then the answer is, in general, no.

First, consider the case if you require $(\mathbb{R}^4,g)$ to be globally hyperbolic.

---

**Counterexample**:

Let $A$ be non-closed, compactly supported one form on $\mathbb{R}^4$. Its exterior derivative $F = dA$ is closed, compactly supported, and not identically zero.

Suppose $g$ is globally hyperbolic. Then by the compact support of $F$ there exists a Cauchy hypersurface $\Sigma$ of $(\mathbb{R}^4, g)$ such that $F, \nabla F$ restricts to zero along $\Sigma$. By the uniqueness of solutions to hyperbolic  PDEs, since $dF = \delta F = 0$, this implies $F \equiv 0$, contradicting the original assumption. Q.E.D.

---

The same argument can be localized as follows:

1. Start with the same compactly supported (in space-time) non-trivial $F$.
2. Suppose, for contradiction, that there exists a metric $g$ that does the job.
3. Find a point $x$ on $\partial~\mathrm{supp}~ F$ such that the boundary is space-like with respect to $g$.
4. Let $\Sigma$ be a space-like hypersurface through $x$ such that $\mathrm{supp}~ F$ is, in a causal convex neighborhood of $x$, to the future of $\Sigma$.
5. Within the convex neighborhood we can find a globally hyperbolic neighborhood of $x$ for which $\Sigma$ is Cauchy. Running the argument above we see that $F$ must vanish identically in this neighborhood, which means that $x$ cannot in fact be on the boundary of $F$'s support. A contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much for give this counterexample！I wonder what if I weaken the condition of the example from compact support to vanishing in infinity would it possible to make some modification to make the proccess work as well？

Comment: @jacktang1996: you will need to complement vanishing at infinity with certain growth/decay rates on your assumption of the new metric $g$. For example, you can start with an arbitrary solution to the Maxwell equations on $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$, and define a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ to itself so that it stretches as you go toward infinity (for example, imagine the mapping on $\mathbb{R}^4$ that looks like $x \mapsto e^{|x|} x$ for $x$ outside the ball of radius 2 and the identity within). Compact support avoids this issue as 0 is smaller than any positive number.